# Using Grep to search for patterns over multipile lines

Tags: linux, grep

I am working in bioinformatics, and I need to count patterns such as GATTACCA in large files that look something like:
"ATTTCCCGATCCGAG **GATT**  (/n)
**ACCA** CGTAGATGATACACGT (etc)"
Is there a way to get Grep to ignore the /n new line character?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: do you just need the count of `GATT\nACCA` occurrence ? and how large the file is?

Comment: How big are the files? Secondly - grep recognizes by newline so it can't match it. But you may be able to use "tr" to replace newline character with space, but again, how big are the files?

Answer (score 1):

I think this may do what you want:

```
tr -d '\n' < file | grep -o GATTACCA
```

It (temporarily) removes the linefeeds from your file (using `tr` and its `-d` option to delete) before passing it into `grep`.

Comment: Thanks! this works easiest so far...  
Now... Any ideas how to parse it into python?
I know how to use simple linux commands in python, but not how to pipe...

Answer (score 1):

You could do this through awk and grep to count the number of occurrences of the word `GATTACCA` in your file,

```
awk -v RS="\0" '{gsub (/\n/,""); print}' file | grep -o 'GATTACCA' | wc -l
```

**Explanation:**

```
RS="\0"            #  Turns the input file into a single record.

gsub (/\n/,"")     #  Removes all the \n character.

grep -o 'GATTACCA' # From the awk output, it fetches the string GATTACCA and prints every match in a new line.

wc -l              #   To count the number of lines
```

Comment: You can use `grep -c` to count instead of `wc`.

Comment: @terdon it displays different result.

Comment: I want number of occurences, not number of lines... so -c would probably be better?

Comment: It displays the number of occurances.did you try this? You may check the output mycode with others.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` and `grep`:

```
sed -n 'H;x;s/\n//g;/GATTACCA/p' input | grep -o GATTACCA
```

Comment: Why the `grep`? Your `sed` command already does its job. Am I missing something?

Comment: there may be multiple occurrences of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You already have two good general answers. Another approach is to use `sed`:

```
perl -pe 's/\n//' file | grep -o GATACA
```

However, if you're working on fasta files, this can be interesting:

```
#! /bin/sh
gawk '{
        if (substr($1,1,1)==">")
        if (NR>1)
                    printf "\n%s\t", substr($0,2,length($0)-1)
        else 
            printf "%s\t", substr($0,2,length($0)-1)
        else 
                printf "%s", $0
}END{printf "\n"}'  "$@"
```

The script above changes fasta format to tbl (seq IDsequence, all on the same line). I very often use it for grepping:

```
FastaToTbl foo.fa | grep GATTACA
```

I also have a TblToFasta to restore the original:

```
#! /bin/sh
# tbl-to-fasta.awk transforms a tbl file into a fasta file, 60 columns per record
# usage=gawk -f tbl-to-fasta TBL_FILE 


gawk '{
  sequence=$NF

  ls = length(sequence)
  is = 1
  fld  = 1

  while (fld < NF)
  {
     if (fld == 1){printf ">"}
     printf "%s " , $fld

     if (fld == NF-1)
      {
        printf "\n"
      }
      fld = fld+1
  }

  while (is <= ls)
  {
    printf "%s\n", substr(sequence,is,60)
    is=is+60
  }
}' "$@"
```